# Offline map app capable of using Garmin Custom Maps / KMZ?

Tags: gps, offline-map

Does anyone know of any map apps for off-line use with GPS support that can view Garmin Custom Map kmz files?

The maps I want to use are the [NZ Topo Map](http://www.topomap.co.nz) ones described here:
http://nztopomap.tumblr.com/post/15386610778/free-linz-nztopo50-based-garmin-custom-maps

Custom Maps is an app I already regularly use which uses the kmz format itself. Apparently the next release will support these kmz files but each image tile in the kmz will show up as a separate map so you'll have to open and view each tile individually - not ideal.

I know there's some map apps out there that will allow you to consume off-line maps created using MOBAC etc. but ideally I'm after one that doesn't require me to play around with file formats - just consume the kmz files as-is directly.

Cheers,
Gavin

Comment: A [search on the Market](https://market.android.com/search?q=kmz+import) shows a couple of likely suspects. Have you tried any of those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [Locus Maps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=menion.android.locus): It not only can import KMZ files (I guess the ones you mean keep to the Keyhole standard, so they should work). You can even have media (pictures) embedded within, and use them in offline mode. Maps also can be downloaded right from within the app, so you can be prepared for your off-road trip.

It also supports a bunch of different map formats (including vector maps), so I would wonder if you were unable to get your mentioned material loaded with Locus.

Besides: excellent support, active forum, and much more... Definitely worth a look.

And no, I'm *not* the developer placing my ad here :)